# bash sed how to replace end of line with single quote and comma

Tags: bash, sed

I tried to replace end of lines in a file with single quote + comma.

Content of test.txt file:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

Expected result:

```
aaa',
bbb',
ccc',
```

I managed to replace the end of lines with comma like this:
`sed  's#$#,#g' test.txt`

but i always fail when trying to convert to single quote + comma.
I tried: `sed  's#$#',#g' test.txt` but the command still awaiting input.

I tried various combination with quotes and double quotes but still fail.

I'd really appreciate your help. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes can't be nested. You have to end the single quotes, add an escaped or quoted single quote, than open a new quoted string.

```
sed 's/$/'\'',/'
sed 's/$/'"'"',/'
```

You can also switch the quotes and use double quotes for the whole expression:

```
sed "s/$/',/"
```

In fact, the substitution needs no quoting in this case, so you can just use

```
sed s/$/\',/
```

Comment: Or switch quotes: `sed "s/$/',/"`. (The dollar sign in general needs to be quoted to prevent parameter expansion in double quotes, but here it's fine because `$/` is not a special parameter expansion.)

Comment: thanks @choroba, i learn something new! you have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a question about `sed` so much as it is a question about quoting in the shell.   If you want a single quote in a string, the 2 typical ways to get it are to enclose it in double quotes or to escape it with `\`.  To pass that string as an argument to `sed` you could do any of:

```
sed "s/\$/',/"
```

or

```
sed s/$/\',/
```

or

```
sed 's/$/'"',/"  # escape the $ with single quotes and the ' with double quotes
```

Comment: thanks! you have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

#### 1)

You should be aware of what character(s) are you using in script of `sed` command.

Simply, if you are using **special characters** (in this case: the "single quote" character) as a character of your script (not character of syntax), technically you can **escape** it.

In `sed`'s script and a lot of programming languages you can use "\" as an escape character.

#### 2)

If your script needs to be (1)quoted (with quoting characters) and you're using a **quoting character** (2)in your script, then the (2) must be different from (1).

#### Result:

The code should be like this example:

```bash
[sinuxnet@hostname]$ sed -r "s/$/\',/g"
```

#### More to read:

1. [Escape character - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)
2. [A Guide to Unix Shell Quoting](https://rg1-teaching.mpi-inf.mpg.de/unixffb-ss98/quoting-guide.html)